# Cmake: Specifiy config specific settings for multi-config cmake project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, cmake, multi-configuration

Cmake novice here, I am currently trying to convert a cmake project that was developed with only single configuration in mind to a multi-config project which can generate visual studio files.

My problem that I can not solve is that in the cmake project there exist logic depending on the variable CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE such as:

```
set(ENABLE_DEBUG TRUE)
if ("${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}" STREQUAL "Release")
  set(ENABLE_DEBUG FALSE)
)
```

Since for multi-config cmake the CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE is empty this way of doing it does not work. The variable ENABLE_DEBUG is then in the cmake project used for stuff such as:

Case 1: Adding libraries to only debug config

```
if(ENABLE_DEBUG)
  list(APPEND LIB_SRC src/lib_debug.cpp)
endif()
add_library(LIB OBJECT LIB_SRC)
```

Case 2: Adding preprocessor flags to only debug config

```
if(ENABLE_DEBUG)
  add_definitions(...)
endif()
```

So what I wonder is if anyone has a workaround for one or both of the cases above that would work for multi-config cmake projects, i.e so that I can specify library additions and preprocessor flags without depending on the CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE variable. Or even better if there a config specific way of setting the ENABLE_DEBUG without depending on the CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE variable?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In CMake common way for config-specific settings for multi-config build tools is using [generator expressions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html).

Command [add_library](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/add_library.html) allows to use generator expressions for source files. E.g. this:

```
add_library(mylib common.c $<$<CONFIG:DEBUG>:debug.c>)
```

creates a library consisted from `common.c` in all configuration plus additional `debug.c` in *Debug* configuration.

Documentation for [add_definitions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/add_definitions.html) doesn't note usage of generator expressions, but documentation for [target_compile_definitions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/target_compile_definitions.html) does:

```
target_compile_definitions(mylib PUBLIC $<$<CONFIG:DEBUG>:-DDEBUG_VAR>)
```