# Generate preprocessor definitions based on CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES

Tags: c++, visual-c++, cmake, macros, c-preprocessor

I want to generate a Visual Studio project with two configurations using cmake. I want cmake to define different preprocessor symbols for these configurations.

I generate the project with the following command

```
cmake -B intermediate/cmake -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -T v142 -DCMAKE_GENERATOR_PLATFORM=x64
```

In my CMakeLists.txt I define configurations:

```
if(CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES)
  set(CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES Debug Release)
endif()
```

Now, how do I define the preprocessor definitions per configuration? The quick search advises against using `if(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE STREQUAL "Release")` because it doesn't work for multiconfiguration generators.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "macros". Are you looking to define different configuration-time [CMake macros](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/macro.html) (e.g. functions without scope)? Or are you looking to conditionally define C++ preprocessor symbols based on the CMake configuration? Can you please clarify?

Comment: @Human-Compiler I've just updated the question, thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conventional way to handle configuration-specific details in a multi-configuration generator is through the use of [generator expressions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html).

Generator expressions allow you to specify symbols, values, flags, etc that will only be expanded at generation time based on the current state of the generator (such as the current build configuration).

For example, you can define custom pre-processor definitions with the `-D` flag with [`target_compile_definitions`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_definitions.html):

```
target_compile_definitions(MyTarget PRIVATE
  $<$<CONFIG:Debug>:DEBUG_ONLY=1>
  $<$<CONFIG:Release>:RELEASE_ONLY=2>
  FOO=3
)
```

<sup>(This example is for `PRIVATE` definitions. Replace this with `PUBLIC` or `INTERFACE` as needed.)</sup>

This adds `-DDEBUG_ONLY=1` to `MyTarget` for Debug builds, `-DRELEASE_ONLY=2` for Release builds, and `-DFOO=3` for all builds.

---

Also see this relevant/similar question: [Cmake: Specifiy config specific settings for multi-config cmake project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46581729/cmake-specifiy-config-specific-settings-for-multi-config-cmake-project)

Comment: This works but the syntax is different. There should be `<INTERFACE|PUBLIC|PRIVATE>` after target and colons instead of commas. So `target_compile_definitions(MyTarget PRIVATE $<$<CONFIG:Debug>:DEBUG_ONLY=1> $<$<CONFIG:Release>:RELEASE_ONLY=2> FOO=3)` works

Comment: @KirillDaybov Ah, my apologies -- I was working from memory when I wrote this